# Rows containing minimum value of a column in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am work with vectors and matrices in R.

In a matrix, I want to return all the rows that has a minimum value of a particular column (for example, the 9th column). The values of that column can be `"Not Available"` also.  How can I do this?

To check the not available values I tried `data <- data[data[,9] != "Not Available"]` but it didn't give me the result I expected.

For Example -

```
Code  Name     Number
1     India     2.3
2     America   3.5
3     China   Not Available
4     Europe    1.2
5    Japan      1.2
```

I want to get all the rows that has minimum value of the column `Number`. The required output is

```
    Code  Name     Number
     4    Europe    1.2
     5   Japan      1.2
```

Not Available values have to be neglected

Comment: In R, it `NA`, not `Not Available`. Have a look at `is.na` function.

Comment: The value of a column can take the string "Not Available". I want to remove the rows that has the value "Not Available"

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: to control for "Not Available" strings use `na.strings='Not Available'` parameter in your data reading function (`read.csv`,`read.table`, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having a 'non-numeric' element in the column, the column will be converted to 'character' or 'factor' class when we read the data with `read.csv/read.table`.  If we use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, the column class will be 'character', otherwise it will be 'factor' by default.

Suppose you read the dataset with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, then we can change the column to 'numeric' by `as.numeric`, the non-numeric elements will be coerced to `NA`.

```
 df1$Number <- as.numeric(df1$Number)
```

If the column is 'factor' class, we may need `as.numeric(as.character(df1$Number))`.  We then `subset` the dataset by the 'min' value of the "Number" column.

```
 subset(df1, Number==min(Number, na.rm=TRUE))
 #    Code   Name Number
 #4    4 Europe    1.2
 #5    5  Japan    1.2
```

This could be also done without changing the class of the 'Number' (i.e. keeping it as 'character' column, but not recommended)

```
 subset(df1, Number== min( as.numeric(Number[Number!='Not Available'])))
 #   Code   Name Number
 #4    4 Europe    1.2
 #5    5  Japan    1.2
```

The best option would be to read the dataset by specifying "Not Available" in the `na.strings` and it will get converted to `NA`.

```
 df1 <- read.table('yourfile.txt', header=TRUE, na.strings='Not Available')
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Code = 1:5, Name = c("India", "America", "China", 
 "Europe", "Japan"), Number = c("2.3", "3.5", "Not Available", 
 "1.2", "1.2")), .Names = c("Code", "Name", "Number"),
 class =   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all rows with "Not Available", you are missing a comma. `data <- data[data[,9] != "Not Available",]` should work.

To figure out which row has the minimum value, use apply and which.min. For e.g.,

```
> foo <- matrix(c(1,2,3,5,4,6,9,7,8), 3, 3)
> foo
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    4    7
[3,]    3    6    8
> apply(foo, 2, which.min)
[1] 1 2 2
```

If you want to ignore rows that have "Not Available" when deciding on which is the minimum row, cast the column as numeric. "Not Available" will become NA, which will be discarded by which.min.

Good luck!